# Taking the absolute value of a DC source (getting the magnitude of the voltage)

Tags: operational-amplifier, design

I found a circuit online that claimed it was an absolute value circuit, plugged it into the simulator where it worked and tried to implement it on a breadboard. I could not get it to work. So my question is this: How does one take a DC input, like a battery and output the magnitude of its voltage regardless of the polarity of the input?

I want to be able to compare some measured voltage of a 9-V battery to some reference where the polarity of the leads don't matter for someone unknowingly connecting them the wrong way...

EDIT: In order to clarify, I'm just asking how one would go about designing a good absolute value circuit. However, the problem with my circuit might be the parts I used. I know it's wired right because I've done it several times over on the breadboard and get an output that's incorrect, of course. I also have plenty of these ICs and switched them out. Basically I've performed all the debugging you can think of.

My refined question: How would one go about making an absolute value circuit with LM324AN op-amp ICs, 1N4004 diodes and resistors aplenty.

Comment: (1) Show us the circuit.   (2) Show us the circuit.   (3) Show us the circuit.   (4) Show us the circuit.   (5) If it worked in the simulator and not in reality and it was a circuit that someone said worked - why are you not asking about what you are doing wrong in reality? (6) If people tell you how to do it, why would you expect better results than you have now where you have a circuit AND it worked in a simulator. (7) Show us the circuit.

Comment: I've read your edit and comments. SHOW us the circuit that you think you have built. Tell us why you think a 1k resistor or a 10k resistor or an LM324 or a 1N4004 can be "the problem". I have given you dozens, literally, of circuits. Have you looked through them for one using an LM324?| Vital question - Have you ever used an LM324 successfully for ANYTHING before where you wired it up? A serious question - please answer.  Look CAREFULLY at the [LM324 power supply connections](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm224.pdf) the opposite of what you may expect. Is that how you have connected them?

Comment: Will this always measure the voltage of a battery?  What resolution and accuracy?  Where does the measurement result go?  Is it just a digital display to a human or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Please show us your circuit. 
It's very likely some small mistake requiring a quick fix.
The fact it worked in simulation but not on the breadboard makes me suspect it's something like you are not using dual supply rails, or you are not working within the opamps specs (e.g. common mode input range, minimum supply voltage, etc)

If you show us your circuit it is almost certain this problem will get fixed very quickly, otherwise people will probably give up. Sorry to be blunt but it seems to be a very common issue here, and I feel many questions go unanswered (or are not answered fully) due to communication problems.

If you don't know how to draw/post a schematic ask and help will be provided. Or even a well taken picture of your circuit (+ power sources) would probably help somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

[Here are dozens and dozens and dozens of absolute value circuit circuits](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=%22absolute+value+circuit%22&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=gELLTu6uL6qZiQfGuu3GDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1111&bih=600).

Each has a link to a web page.

Why do you expect any of these to work better that what you have tried already?
 You need to tell us what you are doing and what happens so that we can assist properly.

---

From the masters - [Burr Brown say](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa068/sboa068.pdf)
 Several circuits plus quality discussion.

[Analog Devices say](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/44-04/absolute.html) - also masters, also good.

[AD OP)& OPamp data sheet - [See fig 9](http://www.mit.edu/~6.301/OP07_a.pdf)

[Lattice say](http://www.msc-ge.com/download/lattice/files/cs1013.pdf) - brief. Useful.

---

A zillion other people say - BUT, show us your circuit. Tell us what you did.

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. The components I have to use are LM324 op-amps, 1N4004 diodes and 10kOhms/1kOhms resistors. I also have an array of capacitors. On one of those links, Burr Brown, I tried to construct the first circuit using the parts I described.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your absolute value circuit with LM324AN op-amp ICs, using two gates and use only one 1N4004 diode. Tutorial on this circuit you can find on:

http://www.cirvirlab.com/index.php/tutorials/77-op-amp-absolute-value-amplifier-with-one-diode.html

And also, you can simulate this circuit on:

http://www.cirvirlab.com/simulation/op_amp_abs_value_ampl_with_one_diode_online.php

Answer (score 1):

Screw the analog circuit and do it digitally.  Set up the analog front end so that the maximum bipolar input range maps to most of the range of a A/D.  Then in firmware, subtract off the 0 reference (the reading it gets when the leads are shorted) and take the absolute value of the result.

Since this appears to be for something like a voltmeter application where the output is for display to a human, there is no issue of conversion speed.  If a 10 or 12 bit A/D built into a microcontroller isn't enough for the resolution you want, you can use a external delta-sigma A/D.  You can get these in 20 bits or more.  Their tradeoff is that they are slow, like 20 ms per conversion, but that's still way faster than you want to display a new value to a human.  The high resolution may allow you to simplify the analog front end even more.  You don't have to be careful to just fill the input range, for example.  Any assymetry from something as simple as a resistor divider can be handled in firmware.

It would help if you explained more how this device will be used.  Is it always to measure the voltage of a battery?  If so, that allows for some simplification.  What is the maximum battery voltage it must be able to handle?  What accuracy and resolution does it need?  What happens to the measurement result?  Will it just be displayed to a human or something else?